# VB windows application create hash and salt

Tags: php, mysql, vb.net, hash

Hi there total newb here again, I am trying to create a windows form app that checks mysql database before continuing. The problem im running into is the hashes im coming up with dont match my databse.

This is the php code that i use on my reg page

```
            $SALT = md5($CURRENTPASSWORD);
            $PASSWORD = hash('sha512', $CURRENTPASSWORD.$SALT);
```

Were $CURRENTPASSWORD is the plaintext password the user has entered and $PASSWORD is the hashed password to match up to the DB

the current code im using:

```
  Public Function HashPassword(ByVal pass As String) As String
    Dim Salt As String = MD5.Create(pass)
    Dim pwd As String = pass & Salt
    Dim hasher As New Security.Cryptography.SHA512CryptoServiceProvider()
    Dim pwdb As Byte() = System.Text.Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(pwd)
    Dim pwdh As Byte() = hasher.ComputeHash(pwdb)
    Return Convert.ToBase64String(pwdh)
End Function
```

but it is giving me errors.

Thanks

Comment: and what is your error?

Comment: You are using UTF8 encoding in VB what encoding is your database set to? What encoding did your PHP page use?

Comment: I have to go along with Namphibian.  I'd guess that you need to use `ASCII` as the `Encoding` but, if that doesn't work, try all the standard options.

Comment: @Namphibian How would i figure out what my php is set to i didtn declare any values

Comment: Ok so i have tried that and its still creating a wrong hash any other suggestions

Comment: So the PHP hash function returns a hex decimal string. You are converting the hash return value to BASE64 encoded string. A base64 encoded string is NOT a hexidecimal representation of the string. I suspect that is what you are doing wrong.